# jquery two clicks instead of one to execute code

Tags: jquery

I found this javascript code, and that's exactly what I'm looking for. This is a Show/Hide code with slide effect.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if($('div.tab').length > 0) {
    $('div.tab').click(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('open')) {
            $(this).removeClass('open');
            $(this).addClass('close');
            $(this).next().slideDown(300);
            return false;
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('close');
            $(this).addClass('open');
            $(this).next().slideUp(300);
            return false;
        }
    })
}
```

Now, I wanted to add a code to show only one DIV at a time, closing opened DIV with slide effect. So, I add some code and it works how I want it to work. But the problem is, when one DIV is opened, and I click on another, new DIV, everything is working, but when I click on already visited DIV, I need two clicks, instead of one, to execute the code. I don't have a knowledge in js coding, so I'm asking here for your help.

Here is a code with my changes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if($('div.tab').length > 0) {
    $('div.tab').click(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('open')) {
            $(this).removeClass('open');
                  $(this).addClass('close')**.siblings('div.container').slideUp(300)**;
            $(this).next().slideDown(300);
            return false;
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('close');
            $(this).addClass('open');
            $(this).next().slideUp(300);
            return false;
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Please post your HTML and when possible, a jsFiddle.net example.

Comment: `$('div.tab').click(function() { $(this).next().slideToggle(300); });` doesn't work for you? this seems like way too much code for what u want.

Comment: Are the `**` typos or are they part of the code you're using?

Comment: this `if($('div.tab').length > 0) {` seems unnecessary

Comment: here is demo link: http://jsfiddle.net/9szef

So, I want for example, if tab1 is opened and I click on tab2, tab1 is automatically closed and tab2 opened. I just want one tab to be opened at a time. Now, on every tab I click it stays open until I click on it again.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it works. I changed some code, and I've got exactly what I'm looking for. It show now one tab at a time, show/hide works when click on the same tab. Maybe it's not a proper coding way, because I don't have a knowledge in js, but it works for me perfectly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('div.tab').click(function() { 
    if($(this).hasClass('open')) {
        $(this).next().slideToggle(300).siblings('div.container').slideUp(300);

    } else {

        $(this).next().slideToggle(300);

    }
})
```

})
http://jsfiddle.net/9szef/1/